# Find&Replace a quoted string with grep | sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep, pipeline, find-replace

I need to remove in a text file all quotation marks which enclosure strings that always begins with the same, but ends in a different way:

```
'something.with.quotation.123' must be something.with.quotation.123
'something.with.quotation.456' must be something.with.quotation.456
```

but quotated strings that doesn't begin with this should not be changed.

I've been working with a grep that finds & prints the quotated strings:

```
grep -o "something\.with\.quotation\.[^']*" file.txt
```

Now I need to pass the results to sed through a pipeline, but it doesn't work:

```
grep -o "something\.with\.quotation\.[^']*" file.txt | sed -i "s/'$'/$/g" file.txt
```

I've been trying with other options (`"s/\'$\'/$/g"`, `"s/'\\$'/\\$/g"`,...) and googling a lot, but no way.

Can you point me to the correct way to get a result from a pipeline in sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `grep` here. Just use `sed` like this:

```
cat file
'something.with.quotation.123'
'something.with.quotation.456'
'foo bar'

sed -E "s/'(something\.with\.quotation\.[^']*)'/\1/g" file
something.with.quotation.123
something.with.quotation.456
'foo bar'
```

Comment: That works, thanks @anubhava. I've voted you, but still not enought reputation to show it.